# Count comments and get average rating from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I just can't figure out how to get average rating and count comments from my mysql database.

I have 3 tables (activity, rating, comments) activity contains the main data the "activities", rating holds the ratings and comments - of course, the ratings.

activity_table

```
id | title |short_desc | long_desc | address | lat | long |last_updated
```

rating_table

```
id | activityid | userid | rating
```

comment_table

```
id | activityid | userid | rating
```

I'm now trying to the data from activity plus the comment_counts and average_rating in one query.

```
SELECT activity.*, AVG(rating.rating) as average_rating, count(comments.activityid) as total_comments
FROM activity LEFT JOIN
     rating
     ON activity.aid = rating.activityid LEFT JOIN
     comments
     ON activity.aid = comments.activityid
GROUP BY activity.aid
```

...doesn't do the job. It gives me the right average_rating, but the wrong amount of comments.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aggregating along two different dimensions.  The Cartesian product generated by the joins affects the aggregation.

So, you should aggregate before the `join`s:

```
SELECT a.*, r.average_rating, COALESCE(c.total_comments, 0) as total_comments
FROM activity a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.activityid, AVG(r.rating) as average_rating
      FROM rating r
      GROUP BY r.activityid
     ) r
     ON a.aid = r.activityid LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.activityid, COUNT(*) as total_comments
      FROM comments c
      GROUP BY c.activityid
     ) c
     ON a.aid = c.activityid;
```

Notice that the outer `GROUP BY` is no longer needed.